# Looping through functions in R

Tags: r, loops, math, equation

I'm trying to write a loop in R that should do the following:

Calculate the square root of a given positive number using Newtons method. My idea is something like this:

```
delta <- 0.0000001
x <- input_value
#DO:
x.new = 0.5*(x + mu/x)
x = x.new
#UNTIL:
abs(xˆ2 - mu) < delta
```

It's meant as a quick way to find the root(s) of a given number.

Does anyone has any ideas as to how to make a loop that does this in R?

Comment: while (abs(xˆ2 - mu) >= delta) { ... }

Comment: https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/newton-raphson-method

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @SteveM . Thank you Grothendieck, I'll take a look at the page!

Comment: Awesome @G. Grothendieck - that does it!

Comment: R has no `do...until` structure.  The `while` serves that purpose.

Comment: That's not entirely true @SteveM , what about `repeat...if...break`?

Comment: Agree there are other constructs.  I gave the OP an obvious one.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I ended up solving my issue: 

# PROGRAM
find_roots <- function(f, a, b, delta = 0.00005, n = 1000) {
  require(numDeriv) # Package for calculating f'(x)
  
  x_0 <- a # Set start value to supplied lower bound
  k <- n # Initialize for iteration results

  for (i in 1:n) {
    dx <- genD(func = f, x = x_0)$D[1] # First-order derivative f'(x0)
    x_1 <- x_0 - (f(x_0) / dx) # Calculate next value x_1
    k[i] <- x_1 # Store x_1
    # Once the difference between x0 and x1 becomes sufficiently small, output the results.
    if (abs(x_1 - x_0) < delta) {
      root.approx <- tail(k, n=1)
      res <- list('root approximation' = root.approx, 'iterations' = k)
      return(res)
    }
    # If Newton-Raphson has not yet reached convergence set x1 as x0 and continue
    x_0 <- x_1
  }
  print('Too many iterations in method')
}

#Example of it working:
func1 <- function(x) {
  x^2 + 3*x + 1
}
# Check out the magic
newton.raphson(func1, 2,3)
```